# Transferring custom map from Google Maps to QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-maps, import, mapping

I've made a map of local archaeological sites using Google Maps (with custom layers) for a local museum. In trying to get it printed, we've decided it would be better to transfer it to QGIS. There are OS map tiles available for the area, and I have all the data already on Google Maps. I just have no idea how to transfer it. Don't even know where to begin apart from in the help section and this forum.

I have downloaded both OS map tiles, and I currently have QGIS 3.16 32 bit version.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. I'm not quite sure what you need help for. Do you have the custom layers you used with google maps saved as file? In what file format? You should be able to drag and drop that file into the QGIS window and it should display in the right place. Add a basemap from the XYZ tiles in the layer panel (for more basemaps, see https://twitter.com/klaskarlsson/status/972757121933733889?lang=en). If that doesn't work and/or for further questions, please revise the question to show exactly what steps you made and where you are stuck. That makes it easier to help.

Comment: Sounds like it is possible - do you have a link to share? there maybe a projection to set if using Ordnance Survey Map Tiles for overlaying the data.

Answer (score 3):

If you have all the data, it seems you just need to [load the data into QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html). Then, you can change the map style and eventually print/save the map however you like. You can use the [QGIS print composer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/map_composer/map_composer.html) for this.

In addition, QGIS has various plugins that supports web mapping services (WMS). One is the [Quick Map Services plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/). With one of these, you can use an online open map service as a background layer on the fly. So, you don't have to download the map tiles if online source is OK. Then, you will have an online map within QGIS (that is similar to Google map).

The official QGIS documentation/tutorial covers other aspects such as visualization pretty well. So it's worthy reading too.

Comment: I think OP asks for **printed** maps.

Comment: @Babel Thanks. I added a link to the print composer. Just trying to help out here. Feel free to add an answer if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly the question is, but I guess your answer points in the right direction.